# Basic Reactjs - error with a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning Reactjs and trying some ES6 features at the same time.
Here's a reactjs component that gives me an error:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Features extends React.Component {

  function myFunc(x, y=5) {
    return x * y;
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
        <p>This is number {this.props.feature}</p>
        {this.myFunc(4,1)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason it does not like the function declaration.

I have tried both syntaxes of function declarations:

```
myFunc: function (x, y=5) {...}
```

and

```
function myFunct(x, y=5) {...}
```

Why does my IDE highlights the space between "function" and "myFunc" and it throws an error:

```
./src/js/components/Features.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: X:/projects/react-gallery/src/js/components/Features.js: Unexpected token (5:11)
  3 | export default class Features extends React.Component {
  4 | 
> 5 |   function myFunc(x, y=5) {
    |            ^
  6 |     return x * y;
  7 |   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `function` keyword. 
Methods is ES6 classes are defined using the [shorthand](/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) notation only, so the method definitions should look like this:

```
export default class Features extends React.Component {

  myFunc(x, y=5) {

  }

  render() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the word function. You can have

```
import React from "react";

export default class Features extends React.Component {

myFunc(x, y=5) {
  return x * y;
}

render() {

  return (
      <div>
      <p>This is number {this.props.feature}</p>
      {this.myFunc(4,1)}
    </div>
  );
}
}
```